# Green flashes when playing video with VLC and Compiz enabled [Ubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu MATE 15.10]

Tags: compiz, 15.10, vlc

When I play video in VLC and Compiz enabled the screen will flash green ( for few seconds ) when I move the mouse, or turn up the volume with the media keys .
The problem started with Ubuntu 15.10 and also occurs on Ubuntu 15.10 with Compiz enabled MATE.
I use the nvidia driver. I tried it with the driver 304 and the driver 352 but the problem persists.

Comment: Just going to comment for now as I am not familiar with `VLC`. I had an issue with this on `smplayer`, same `green` flashing, the solution was to go in to the applications settings and change the `output driver` to `vdpau`, sorry I can be more specific.

Comment: I try on VLC but does not work :(

Answer (score -1):

I has the same issue. Had found something similar out [there](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/09/03/fix-for-flickering-fullscreen-application-with-compiz/).

open **compizconfig**
go general -> composite
uncheck "**unredirect fullscreen windows**" flag
or better fix line "**unredirect match**" changing "**=Vlc**" to "**=vlc**".